# Unity How Do I get these blocks

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to use these cubes in my own game but I have literally no idea how he got them. Look at the cubes with the black outline, the walls the ground the roof, how do I get a cube with the outline like that. I know this is a stupid question but I have tried but I cant find out why.
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe the plugin Probuilder?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Probuilder is include in Unity.. see package manager to install it and video aout this plugin..and i know you could do objects like these..

Comment: Oh i read that wrong I thought u meant get a plugin for pro builder. I tried pro builder but i couldnt find anything like this

Comment: sorry i thought that!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not individual cubes.
Take as example one of the walls, probably it's a single cube (rectangular prism) for each wall, the trick is that it has a material with a texture applied to it and a normal map.

In simple words:

- **A texture** is an image containing the colors the object has. In this case the blue color of the walls and the black lines simulating cubes.
- **A normal map** is something like an image but it contains information about the "depth" of each pixel in the image. In this case it indicates that the black lines should be "deeper" than the rest of the image.
- **A material** is the object that combines the texture with the normal map and along with other settings can tell the computer how exactly it should look like.

Of course this is only a very brief definition, if you want to know more about it I recommend you to read about: Materials, textures and shaders in Unity. There are some tutorials in Unity web page.

Comment: This is the perfect answer, but I still don't know how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

Use photoshop to create a single tile of each type of block and use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I dont have photoshop

Comment: Is there anything to use instead

Comment: so its going to be a 2d tile rather than a 3d cube?

Comment: You can use other different tools like GIMP or even https://www.photopea.com/ that is a photoshop but online and free. And of course its going to be a 2D cube, the image you posted aren't 3D neither.

Comment: thanks you! how could you tell they are not 3d? They look like cubes to me

Comment: Its looks like 3D because the author is using Normal maps textures to play with the light and the shades and make it looks like 3D. Besides that no one would use that amount of 3D cubes if you don't want to interact with every single one of them. By the way, don't forget to choose my answer if you are happy with it!

Comment: Is it possible to make them using pro builder? Sorry if these are really lame questions

Comment: Yes, you should watch some tutorials about pro builder.

Comment: Ok thank you !!! One more thing though, I have watched a few tutorials on pro builder but don't know how to get the black outline, could you please tell me how? Thanks!